# Ansible Playbook for setting up Apache Server locally doesn't match hosts

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ansible

I have an Ansible Playbook that is meant to create an Apache server locally on my machine. However, everytime I try running the playbook I get the following error messages:

```
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: apache
skipping: no hosts matched
```

This is what my Ansible Playbook looks like:

```
- hosts: apache
  tasks:
     - name: install apache2
       apt: name=apache2 update_cache=yes state=latest
```

And this is what my `ansible.cfg` and `hosts` files look like:

ansible.cfg:

```
[defaults]
hostfile = hosts
inventory = /etc/ansible/hosts
```

hosts:

```
myserver ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_user=ubuntu ansible_connection=local
```

This is all on an Ubuntu VM, if that matters. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Alright, I no longer get that error after doing Shraddheya's fix, but now I am getting this error:

```
fatal: [myserver]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "changed": false, "failed_modules": {"ansible.legacy.setup": {"ansible_facts": {discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"}, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}}, "msg": "The following modules fialed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup\n"}
```

Comment: What is unclear with `sudo: a password is required`? <= set the become password in your inventory/playbook/task/command line. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#become-connection-variables

Answer (score 2):

Alter your hosts file a little to include `myserver` in `apache` hosts-group,
`hosts` file must read:

```
[apache]
myserver ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_user=ubuntu ansible_connection=local
```